# undefined method `create_db' for #<Mysql:0x000000018f2590> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'mysql'
db=Mysql.new '127.0.0.1','root','123456'
db.create_db 'testdb'
```

error message:

```
test.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `create_db' for #<Mysql:0x000000015d0ab0> (NoMethodError)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is still in the API, [`create_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-create-db.html) cannot be used since `mysql4.1`.

> This function is deprecated. It is preferable to use mysql_query() to
>   issue an SQL CREATE DATABASE statement instead.

Therefore you need to use [`query`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-query.html) as

```
require 'mysql'
db = Mysql::new('127.0.0.1','root','123456')
db.query("create database testdb;");
db.close
```